# Programatically setting the background colour of list item on state pressed

Tags: android, listview

Hi I'm trying to change the background colour of a list item when it is pressed i need to do this programmatically as the colour it needs to be set is parsed from a string in my activity. Does anyone know how to do this?

I have tried setting the background of the view but this just changes the background colour not just only when its selected.

```
public void onItemSelected(View v, int position, JSONObject itemDict, String bgColor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(  v.isActivated() == true){
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(bgColor));
            TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView docType = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.doctype);


            if(title != null){
            title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(bgColor));
            }

            if(docType != null){
            docType.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            }

        }

        Intent sectionMain = new Intent(this, SectionDetail.class);
        sectionMain.putExtra("color", bgColor);
        sectionMain.putExtra("fullDict", itemDict.toString());

        startActivity(sectionMain); 

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried setting an `OnTouchListener`?

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            v.setBackgroundColor(pressColor);
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            v.setBackgroundColor(normalColor);
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

assuming you have defined `pressColor` and `normalColor`